# Sql Server Agent job failing to execute stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, sql-server-agent

I have a stored procedure that I can execute in SSMS with a non domain SQL Server user.

This stored procedure selects data from tables in one database (DB1) truncates and selects into a table in DB2.

The user has datareader,datawriter and dbowner for both databases.

**Problem:**

When I execute the stored procedure via SS Agent with execute as the user I get the following error

> The server principal [user] is not able to access the database [DB1]
>   under the current security context.

**Actions taken So far:**

I have tried to resolve this so far by:

1. Turning on db chaining for both databases
2. Deleted the user from DB1 and added again
3. Checked using `EXEC sp_change_users_login @Action=’Report’` to see if user orphaned. As this is a database that is a restore of a live one. However I added the user after the restore. **The user was not listed as orphaned**

Comment: Did you try execute as caller?

Comment: @Giorgi Nakeuri added execute as caller to the stored proc and still not working via SSA

Comment: You better ask the question in http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @PeterCampbell, one or the other db could not be trustworthy for the login context. ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET TRUSTWORTHY ON.

Comment: @PeterCampbell, the only other thing that's obvious is if the user is properly mapped. User mappings should show both databases.

Comment: @EmacsUser user shows for both databases

Comment: @PeterCampbell, not to beat this to death, but are the users the same and not just two different users using the same login?

Comment: @EmacsUser I have tried setting trustworthy on, but getting a permissions issue despite the user I am altering with being in the server sysadmin role as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187861(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible workaround if you don't want to have the owner be sa is to have the user be a member of msdb and grant the the SQLAgentOperatorRole in msdb. See if that works.

But to be honest, either use sa or a dedicated service account with enough permissions. It's better if the job runs under that context.

Comment: user already has SQLAgentOperatorRole in msdb, I agree sa would work, but its disabled on this instance.

Comment: set up a dedicated service account removed the local user from the SSA job and the job is running properly.

Comment: try this.. grant CONNECT and CONNECT REPLICATED to the user on both sides.

Comment: Glad the dedicated service account worked for you.  Its a cleaner way than the local user.  Have fun, enjoy the day